# earphones wiring button

Tags: audio

my earphones broke down and I acted stupid and cut the wire, I put on a new jack and my right earphone works like a charm, but the left one has a significant lower volume... when i press the button, the volume goes up to normal.. I think I wired something wrong. Please help me.

I have no measuring equipment like a multimeter.

the wires are as followed:

Jack:

- thick copper wire
- one wire with a blue plastic tube in the middle and green/red wires around it
- one wire with a green plastic tube in the middle and copper/green wires around it.

earphones: two separate wires:

wire 1:

- one green wire
- one copper wire

wire 2:

- one blue wire
- one red wire
- one copper wire

I connected the thick copper wire with the two other wires(I am pretty sure that's ground)
I connected the red wires with each other,
the blue plastic wire to the blue earphone wire
the green plastic wire to the green earphone wire...

I did not connect the green wire surrounding the blue plastic wire and the green/copper wire surrounding the green plastic wire.

I found that connecting two of the three wires in form the earphones (the left) doesn't work and for the right one I have no problem.

I no one knows how to fix it, i think i will have to tape down the pause button on the left earphone.

thanks in advance[image: this is an image of how I connected things]

Comment: Normal ear phones do not have buttons.  This makes if difficult to to help you.  Despite this, I am curious: Did the old plug have tip, ring, ring & sleeve?  Does the new one only have tip, ring & sleeve?  Also, if this is an Apple product you may be up against DRM chips.

Comment: the original earphones are the raccat syva, with a  button and mic. the new jack plug I think is from a old pair of samsung earphones with mic, button and volume control(tip ring ring sleeve)

Comment: Ah, I think you are dipping into the realm of "needing to find someone who did this exact thing and it worked".  There are all kinds of things companies do to make an in-line remote control work.  It is likely you need to backwards engineer this.  And for that you need tools and (probably) both sets of ear phones so that you can understand how each company implemented their solution.

Comment: I've come up with a suggestion.  However it doesn't fit into the comments and I can't edit the comments should there be an error in what I describe.  So I'll chance it and make it into an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess.  As always without the proper "tools" there is the possibility of causing permanent damage.  I would avoid pushing any in-line buttons during this test. I might try connecting only the red/green pair from the jack to the red/copper pair from the phones.  If this produces sound in one ear phone leave the connection alone (point A).  If it does not, I would then connect the red/green pair from the jack to the blue/copper pair from the phones (that would be the same copper phone wire).  If this produces the expected sound leave it alone (point B).  If it doesn't then I'm stumped (stop).

If there is sound coming out of 1 ear phone after getting to "point A", I may next try connecting the copper/green pair from the jack to the copper/blue pair from the phones (that would be the same copper phone wire).  If there is the expected sound from both ear phones, I think we are done.  If not, keep going.

If there is sound coming out of 1 ear phone after getting to "point B" or if continuing from above, I may next try connecting the copper/green pair from the jack to the copper/green pair from the phones.  If there is the expected sound from both ear phones, I think we are done.  If not then I'm stumped (stop).

If successful, you may want to consider connecting any shielding wire.  Shielding is not necessarily needed for the phones to function unless it is used as a ground reference.  And is usually not critical as its primary purpose is to mitigate noise problems.

Last note, the above description is very specific with respect to the wire colors and your good description of how they appear in the cables.  So even if this does work, it may not work in general (for everyone).  But the procedure of trying 1 thing at a time is an important component of almost every problem solving procedure.